# Two inline blocks (right fixed)

Tags: css, html

i need to to the following:

There are 2 inline colums
 - left - minimum width e.g 50 em, max-width e.g 75 em;
 - right - fixed e.g. 20em.

If width of the screen is less than 95em, columns go one below other.

I tryed to do it in following way:

```
 <style type="text/css">
   .layout {width:100%;}
   .col1 {background-color:gold; display:inline; min-width:50em; max-width:70em;}
   .col2 {background-color:red; display:inline; width:20em;}
  </style>

<div class="layout">
    <div class="col1">Column1</div>
    <div class="col2">Column2</div>
</div>
```

but no success - col1's min-width doesn't work. Can anyone give me right example? I googled for solution but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `display:inline-block;` instead of `display:inline`. You can't set widths on inline elements.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fn2Xy/)

UPDATE:

If you want the width of `.col1` to be limited to the window's width, do this:

```
<style type="text/css">
   .layout {width:100%; min-width:95em;}
   .col1 {background-color:gold; display:inline-block; width: 50em; max-width:100%;}
   .col2 {background-color:red; display:inline-block; width:20em;}
</style>

<div class="layout">
    <div class="col1">Column1</div>
    <div class="col2">Column2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You missed `min-width:50em;` on `.col1` in your demo - here you go: http://learn.javascript.ru/play/X8g5A

Comment: 2 be fair it's not exactly what i want. If you resize page making it smaller golden column col1 doesn't resize at all. M.b. my description of the task isn't perfect - i can show how to do my task with tables - all works perfect http://learn.javascript.ru/play/6eAjb

Comment: OK, so you need the `width` of `.col1` to be `50em` and its `max-width` to be `100%`. That should do it: http://learn.javascript.ru/play/0Ll42

Comment: Zougen Moriver, thanks a lot for you answers, but I haven't reach ideal yet. Gold (column 2) resizes only when it goes above red (one below another) and I need gold bar to change it's size when it inline with red, depends on browser side. Smthng like this (numbers used only to show example, they aren't exact): 

Screen resolution 1600*1200 col1 width 90em col2 width 20em (inline-block)
Screen resolution 1280*1200 col1 width 50em col2 width 20em (inline block)
Screen resolution 1024*768 col1 width 90em col2 width 20em (one below other)

Comment: You should include details like that in your question :) Look into CSS media queries to change styles based on window width, and ask another question if you get stuck with that.

Comment: Zougen, I didn't knew about media queries and after 5 mins of reading about it my problem is solved. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Nice one. No worries :)

Answer (score 0):

Give `min-width` to `.layout{}`:

```
.layout{
    width:100%;
    min-width:95em;
}
```